# Accessing other users signatures via REST API

Tags: docusignapi

I'm trying to make an app that would make CRUD operations on Users and their Signatures.

I'm able to make an Get request on admin user but on the another user I'll get error

```
"errorCode": "INVALID_USERID",
"message": "Invalid UserId. UserId specified in request uri does not match authenticated user."
```

I'm using Authorization Code Grant for getting Access token and API calls instead of SDK.

Comment: Please EDIT your question to add (a lot) more information so we can help you: which authentication flow are you using? Are you using the API directly or via an SDK? (Which SDK?) It sounds like you are having trouble obtaining an access token, is that right? If not, what API method are you trying to call?

Comment: I've added Auth Flow and Api calls.
Nah, I don't have problem with getting Access token. I can Get Signature for the default user but if I try to get Signatures of another user I get the error. 
Seems like I don't have the access to it.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't yet know what you're trying to do. What do you mean by "get signatures of another user?" Can you provide a description of your use case?

Comment: I have User1. The admin of the account, with integrator key and everything. I'm using it to authenticate against docusign API so I can create another users and signatures for them. 
I can create new user without problem. But if I try to create signature or make GET request for signatures of the other user I get error.

Comment: I switched the OAuth method to JWT. Now I get error
{"error":"consent_required"}

And I can't find a way how to give consent from the users I create through API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your application can **impersonate** another user if you use the JWT grant.

But, as you've discovered, that user must first grant consent to be impersonated by your application.

To grant consent individually, you must be able to login as the user. (Eg, go through the email verification process used for new user accounts, create a password, etc.)

Consent can also be granted at the organization level if you have Organization Administration turned on and if you've "captured" a DNS domain. SSO is not needed.

When you impersonate someone you can't sign an envelope for them. -- You can't programmatically sign an envelope for yourself or anyone. Signing is only done by real humans.

Exception: the DocuSign Signature Appliance can programmatically digitally sign documents if it is equipped with the signer's public/private key pair. A use case for this feature is digitally signing (many) invoices that are being automatically sent.